# Is there a way to assign automatic values to a 2D array in Python with a specific pattern without filling the whole array with just one value?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to create a really basic snake-like console game just to test Python's functionality, yet I'm having issues with an algorithm I created for setting up the game map. I need the map borders to be set up as '*#*' and the map body as a space ' ' but for some reason the whole map is being shown as hashes, even after printing out the results in the decisive *if* function. Here's the code:

```
class GameMap:
def __init__(self):
    self.border_icon = '#'
    self.body_icon = ' '
    self.x_size = 0
    self.y_size = 0
    self.map_grid = []

def create_grid(self, map_size):
    if map_size == 1:
        self.x_size = 40
        self.y_size = 20
    elif map_size == 2:
        self.x_size = 80
        self.y_size = 40
    else:
        self.x_size = 120
        self.y_size = 60

    self.map_grid = [[None]*self.x_size]*self.y_size

    for row in range(self.y_size):
        for column in range(self.x_size):
            if row==0 or row==self.y_size-1 or column==0 or column==self.x_size-1:
                print('set: '+self.border_icon)
                self.map_grid[row][column] = self.border_icon
            else:
                print('set: '+self.body_icon)
                self.map_grid[row][column] = self.body_icon

def setup(self, map_type):
    map_templates = {
        1: 'Small Map (40x20)',
        2: 'Medium Map (80x40)',
        3: 'Big Map (120x60)'
    }
    if map_type not in map_templates:
        print('Invalid map type, starting a game with the default configuration...')
        map_type = 1

    print('Starting game: '+map_templates.get(map_type,'Invalid map type'))
    self.create_grid(map_type)
```

This is the map class, in order to access it I just create a map object and call for the setup.
The issue is that whenever I display the matrix, the whole map is filled with '*#*' and no spaces whatsoever. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the `For-loop`, but, issue is in this line:

```
self.map_grid = [[None]*self.x_size]*self.y_size
```

Say your `self.x_size` is 5 and `self.y_size` is 10, then, this line evaluates to this:

```
[[None, None, None, None, None]] * 10
```

At this very moment you have a list having reference to inner list (which is its only element). Now, if you multiply with `self.y_size`, you are just getting 9 (in this case) more references to inner list. This is a very common misunderstanding among new Python developers.

There are 2 possible solutions for your problem:

**Nested List Comprehension:**

```
self.map_grid = [[None for _ in range(self.x_size)] for _ in range(self.y_size)]
```

**OR**

```
self.map_grid = [[None] * self.x_size for _ in range(self.y_size)]
```

Comment: @NibboNSX, users must take this to account, that if they find the answer correct and it resolves their issue, then kindly mark 
that as answer. so that if someone have the same issue in future they can get a handy help without asking a new question. That's how things work here . Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0):

I just changed that block:

```
 for row in range(self.y_size):
    for column in range(self.x_size):
        if row==0 or row==self.y_size-1 or column==0 or column==self.x_size-1:
            print('set: '+self.border_icon)
            self.map_grid[row][column] = self.border_icon
        else:
            print('set: '+self.body_icon)
            self.map_grid[row][column] = self.body_icon
```

and I think it works

```
    row=0
    column=0
    while(row<=self.x_size):
        while(column<=self.y_size):
            if row==0 or row==self.x_size:
                print("#",end="")
            elif column==0 or column==self.y_size:
                print("#",end="")
            else:
                print(" ",end="")
            column=column+1
        column=0
        print()
        row=row+1
```